# Clearing a web page from a view

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to clear a webview from the view in my application.

I clear this by using: `MyWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");`

This works sometimes, but  other times when I load the emulator this gives a force close error:

```
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at com.edu.WordJumbleMain$5.onClick(WordJumbleMain.java:168)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-18 14:58:29.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any other way to clear the webview from the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Raj,

Perhaps you simply want to use the [`clearView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearView%28%29) method?

Comment: Thanks, but I add this method as MyWebView.clearView(); and this still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

how to hide the "Web Page not available" text when web View fails to load the page. MyWebView.clearView() is not working.